# Obtain value corresponding to max value of another variable in Stata

Tags: stata

Is it possible to obtain in Stata the observation value in one variable that corresponds to the max of another variable? (Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13367874/how-to-retrieve-the-value-which-corresponding-to-the-max-in-an-other-column-in-s) in SQL).

**Edit:** You are right, Nick. I was light on details. My dataset looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlMMcUn_SxZGdDJ2SjY1UllsMDZtN05HTmRJU0FGZnc&usp=sharing) (wfs Google Docs table; couldn't figure out how to format a table here).

My aim is to create two variables with the "col" and "row" values corresponding to the max of "pressure" by side and condition.

Answer (score 2):

That is rather general, but indeed yes is the short answer. Here are two specific examples, one for overall maximum, the other for maxima within groups.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. su mpg , meanonly

. list weight if mpg == r(max)

     +--------+
     | weight |
     |--------|
 71. |  2,040 |
     +--------+

. egen maxmpg = max(mpg), by(rep78)

. list rep78 maxmpg weight if mpg == maxmpg

    +-------------------------+
    | rep78   maxmpg   weight |
    |-------------------------|
 7. |     .       26    2,230 |
14. |     3       29    2,110 |
18. |     2       24    2,750 |
40. |     1       24    2,730 |
45. |     .       26    2,520 |
    |-------------------------|
52. |     2       24    2,690 |
63. |     4       30    1,980 |
71. |     5       41    2,040 |
    +-------------------------+
```

Some general notes:

1. Watch out for ties, especially when data are (held as) integers.
2. Watch out for missing values on either your selection variable or any other. (Missing values are `sort`ed to the end of the dataset, for example.)
3. Watch out for precision problems when comparing with maxima. (Not documented here in this answer, but `search precision, faq` leads to many discussions.)

http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0055 discusses related techniques.

(UPDATE)

Sounds like

```
. bysort side condition (pressure) : gen rowmax = row[_N]

. bysort side condition (pressure) : gen colmax = col[_N]
```

For a tutorial on `by:` see http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004 That's a link to a free .pdf you should read. As before, if you have missing values on `pressure`, you will need something different, as the missings will be sorted to the end of each block of `side` and `condition`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nick. I have edited the post with a clearer explanation of my original question.

Comment: what if we wanted weights for top 3 highest MPGs specifically?

Comment: @JyothsnaHarithsa Or seven, or 666 highest. As the reply  -- just extend the same technique, but watch out for the same problems -- may not satisfy you, so also that is a new question to be asked as such.